# Python - Writing all text file contents for specified years from a html web url

Tags: python, url, urllib

I have a web page that contains several links to text files that are labeled like: "Saturday, July 06, 2013" with a hyperlink to their files that end in: *_130706.txt. Can someone direct me to a script that will write all of the contents of files that contain *2013* in their label to a text file? The text files are found in the  tag. So far I have been able to output the html in xml format:

```
from lxml import html

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import urllib




string = '2013'

my_url = 'url'

html = urllib.request.urlopen(my_url).read()

html_page = BeautifulSoup(html, features='lxml')
```

any suggestions?

Comment: please offer more detail? like the picture and the html code of the website?

Comment: http://web.mta.info/developers/turnstile.html

Comment: Hyperlinks are embedded into the labels. I am basically looking to write all of the contents of the 2012/2013 files to a single text file.

Comment: Okey, i understand, i will try to give you an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

if __name__ == "__main__":
    headers = {
        "Host": "web.mta.info",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                      "Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36",
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,"
                  "application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Accept-Language": "zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
        "Cookie": "_ga=GA1.2.941711768.1610503542; _gid=GA1.2.1497562578.1610503542; "
                  "cookie_session=!AnxZS989I2WWEppONIhq3dHOsu/4VyPMB2uUQ7VhQ58NbigvNqrV3gdJ3wNP/qYFl3l5MCbT0vDDeP"
                  "+C3j5QyQ8/JwL1WYLBgiBYr59v "
    }
    r = requests.get('http://web.mta.info/developers/turnstile.html', headers)
    r.raise_for_status()
    html = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")
    result = ""
    for k in soup.find_all('a'):
        if str(k.string).endswith("2013"):
            # all<a> in 2013
            url = k["href"]
            r2 = requests.get("http://web.mta.info/developers/" + url, headers)
            r2.raise_for_status()
            result += r2.text
    # do some os
    print(result)
```

Comment: It found the first text file in <a href> but gave this error:

Invalid URL 'data/nyct/turnstile/turnstile_131228.txt': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://data/nyct/turnstile/turnstile_131228.txt?

131228 is the first file for 2013 because it is ordered from newest->oldest

Comment: The <a href> tag only contains "data/nyct/turnstile/turnstile_131228.txt". The link really is:
http://web.mta.info/developers/data/nyct/turnstile/turnstile_131228.txt. So I think we need to append http://web.mta.info/developers/ before the url. 

Does this make sense?

Comment: @pats_1966 Oh, i know, it is relative url in <a>, i will fix it

Comment: r2 = requests.get('http://web.mta.info/developers/' + url, headers) ??

Comment: How would you alter this to include multiple years. Such as 2012/2013?

Comment: if str(k.string).endswith("2013" || "2012") - something like this?

Comment: @pats_1996 yes, like this or add a array `if str(k.string).endswith("2013") or str(k.string).endswith("2012")`

Comment: @pats_1996 um..if this answer help you and it can run, plz mark it to the answer to help more people.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much. This took awhile to run, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You know that the contents of all these files is kinda... huge ?
Here a python3 solution without external libs, using regular expressions to find the links:

```py
from urllib import request
import re
import os

strings = ['2013', '2014']
output = 'huge.txt'

my_url = 'http://web.mta.info/developers/turnstile.html'
path, page = os.path.split(my_url)
print("path:", path, "page:", page)

html = request.urlopen(my_url).read().decode("utf8")
urls = []
for string in strings:
  urls += [ u for u in re.findall(r'<a href="([^"]+)">([^<]+)</a>', html)
    if u[1].find(string) >= 0 ]

print("links found:", len(urls))
open(output,"wt").write("")

for url in urls:
  #link = os.path.join(path, url[0])
  link = path + "/" + url[0]
  print ("  link:", link, "  name:", url[1])
  open(output, "at").write ( request.urlopen(link).read().decode("utf8") )
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion here. I'm getting an error here that says: 
"HTTP Error 404: Not Found"

It does output this though:

path: http://web.mta.info/developers page: turnstile.html
links found: 104
link: http://web.mta.info/developers\data/nyct/turnstile/turnstile_131228.txt   name: Saturday, December 28, 2013

Comment: Well, seemingly Windows does the path.join wrong with links... fixed

Comment: Is there anything specifically I need to do to print this output? I'm ultimately looking to take the output file and feed it into a data frame to manipulate it. It looks like output is of type string. 

Looking to do something like this:

df = pd.read_csv(output)

Comment: This code writes all the text pages into one big file called 'huge.txt' which is getting really huge. It is of type text file. That is also the reason why I write every page independently. To ensure it is fitting the RAM and isn't lagging. You could feed the text pages directly to pandas' pd.DataFrame() function. But a call to df=pd.read_csv('huge.txt') or df=pd.read_csv(output) should work either. Caching to a file isn't a bad idea at all with these hundreds of megabytes. You might check if 'huge.txt' exists with if(os.path.exists(output)) before html=request.urlopen(...) call.